# Append child in XML document using Classic ASP

Tags: xml, dom, vbscript, asp-classic, gpx

I have the following asp-classic code which appends 3 variables into an XML document, 'location_x', 'location_y' and 'date_and_time'.

The ASP-Classic code - creates or appends an existing XML document.

```
Function LoadObjecttoXML(strXMLFilePath, strFileName)

    Dim objDom
    Dim objGpx
    Dim objWpt
    Dim objRte
    Dim objRtept
    Dim objDateTime
    Dim objattLat
    Dim objattLon
    Dim objPI
    Dim blnFileExists

    'Instantiate the Microsoft XMLDOM
    Set objDom = server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objDom.preserveWhiteSpace = True

    blnFileExists = objDom.Load(strXMLFilePath & "\" & strFileName)

    If blnFileExists = True Then
        Set objGpx = objDom.documentElement
    Else
        'GPX root element and append it to the XML document.
        Set objGpx = objDom.createElement("gpx")
        objDom.appendChild objGpx                                   
    End If

    Set objWpt = objDom.createElement("wpt")

        'Create "Lat" attribute'
        Set objattLat = objDom.createAttribute("lat")
        objattLat.Text = (location_x)
        objWpt.setAttributeNode objattLat

        'Create "Lon" attribute'
        Set objattLon = objDom.createAttribute("lon")
        objattLon.Text = (location_y)
        objWpt.setAttributeNode objattLon

        'Create "date_and_time" element'
        Set objDateTime = objDom.createElement("time")
        objDateTime.Text = (date_and_time)

    'Append "wpt" element as a child container element "gpx".'
    objGpx.appendChild objWpt
    'Append the "time" element as a child of the "wpt" element'
    objWpt.appendChild objDateTime

    'Append "rte" element only once'
    If blnFileExists = True Then
        Set objRte = objDom.documentElement
    Else
        Set objRte = objDom.createElement("rte")
        objGpx.appendChild objRte
    End If

    Set objRtept = objDom.createElement("rtept")

        'Create "Lat" attribute'
        Set objattLat = objDom.createAttribute("lat")
        objattLat.Text = (location_x)
        objRtept.setAttributeNode objattLat

        'Create "Lon" attribute'
        Set objattLon = objDom.createAttribute("lon")
        objattLon.Text = (location_y)
        objRtept.setAttributeNode objattLon

        'Create "date_and_time" element'
        Set objDateTime = objDom.createElement("time")
        objDateTime.Text = (date_and_time)

    'Append "rtept" element as a child container element "rte".'
    objRte.appendChild objRtept
    'Append the "time" element as a child of the "rtept" element'
    objRtept.appendChild objDateTime

    If blnFileExists = False Then
        'Create the xml processing instruction - and append to XML file
        Set objPI = objDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
        objDom.insertBefore objPI, objDom.childNodes(0)
    End If

    'Save the XML document.
    objDom.save strXMLFilePath & "\" & strFileName

    Set objDom = Nothing
    Set objGpx = Nothing
    Set objWpt = Nothing
    Set objRte = Nothing
    Set objRtept = Nothing
    Set objDateTime = Nothing
    Set objattLat = Nothing
    Set objattLon = Nothing
    Set objPI = Nothing
    Set blnFileExists = Nothing

End Function

On Error Resume Next

'File path c:\
LoadObjecttoXML "c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\xml","doc.xml"

'error check
If err.number <> 0 then
    Response.write("Error: " & err.number )
Else
    Response.write("Success!")
End If
```

The problem I have is when I append the variables for a second time, the appended XML isn't placed inside the correct elements.

For example the XML code would look something like this on the first append:

```
<gpx>
    <wpt lat="52.000" lon="-1.000">
        <time>2016-09-23 23:38:00</time>
    </wpt>
    <rte>
        <rtept lat="52.000" lon="-1.000">
            <time>2016-09-23 23:38:00</time>
        </rtept>
    </rte>
</gpx>
```

When I append for the second time:

```
<gpx>
    <wpt lat="52.000" lon="-1.000">
        <time>2016-09-23 23:38:00</time>
    </wpt>
    <rte>
        <rtept lat="52.000" lon="-1.000">
            <time>2016-09-23 23:38:00</time>
        </rtept>
    </rte>
    <wpt lat="52.100" lon="-1.100">
        <time>2016-09-23 23:39:00</time>
    </wpt>
    <rte>
        <rtept lat="52.100" lon="-1.100">
            <time>2016-09-23 23:39:00</time>
        </rtept>
    </rte>
</gpx>
```

I would like the XML to append like this:

```
<gpx>
    <wpt lat="52.000" lon="-1.000">
        <time>2016-09-23 23:38:00</time>
    </wpt>
    <wpt lat="52.100" lon="-1.100">
        <time>2016-09-23 23:39:00</time>
    </wpt>
    <rte>
        <rtept lat="52.000" lon="-1.000">
            <time>2016-09-23 23:38:00</time>
        </rtept>
        <rtept lat="52.100" lon="-1.100">
            <time>2016-09-23 23:39:00</time>
        </rtept>
    </rte>
</gpx>
```

I'd love to hear of any suggestions; hints or tips, on how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking `blnFileExists` is useless and irrelevant with `rte`. Remove the following part first.

```vb
'Append "rte" element only once'
If blnFileExists = True Then
    Set objRte = objDom.documentElement
Else
    Set objRte = objDom.createElement("rte")
    objGpx.appendChild objRte
End If
```

Instead you need to make sure that there's a `rte` in the document.

To check whether a node exists you can use [selectSingleNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846(v=vs.85).aspx). It simply returns the first matched object. If no nodes match the expression, returns `Nothing`.

```vb
'Append "rte" element only once'
Set objRte = objGpx.SelectSingleNode("rte")
If objRte Is Nothing Then ' rte does not exist
    Set objRte = objDom.createElement("rte")
    objGpx.appendChild objRte
End If
```

---

#### Update #1

**ASP File:**

```vb
<%
' junk variables required in the function
Dim location_x, location_y, date_and_time
    location_x = 56
    location_y = 43
    date_and_time = Now

'calling function twice
'will result an example.xml file near the asp file

LoadObjecttoXML Server.Mappath("."), "example.xml"
LoadObjecttoXML Server.Mappath("."), "example.xml"

Function LoadObjecttoXML(strXMLFilePath, strFileName)

    Dim objDom
    Dim objGpx
    Dim objWpt
    Dim objRte
    Dim objRtept
    Dim objDateTime
    Dim objattLat
    Dim objattLon
    Dim objPI
    Dim blnFileExists

    'Instantiate the Microsoft XMLDOM
    Set objDom = server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objDom.preserveWhiteSpace = True

    blnFileExists = objDom.Load(strXMLFilePath & "\" & strFileName)

    If blnFileExists = True Then
        Set objGpx = objDom.documentElement
    Else
        'GPX root element and append it to the XML document.
        Set objGpx = objDom.createElement("gpx")
        objDom.appendChild objGpx                                   
    End If

    Set objWpt = objDom.createElement("wpt")

        'Create "Lat" attribute'
        Set objattLat = objDom.createAttribute("lat")
        objattLat.Text = (location_x)
        objWpt.setAttributeNode objattLat

        'Create "Lon" attribute'
        Set objattLon = objDom.createAttribute("lon")
        objattLon.Text = (location_y)
        objWpt.setAttributeNode objattLon

        'Create "date_and_time" element'
        Set objDateTime = objDom.createElement("time")
        objDateTime.Text = (date_and_time)

    'Append "wpt" element as a child container element "gpx".'
    objGpx.appendChild objWpt
    'Append the "time" element as a child of the "wpt" element'
    objWpt.appendChild objDateTime

    'Append "rte" element only once'
    Set objRte = objGpx.SelectSingleNode("rte")
    If objRte Is Nothing Then ' rte does not exist
        Set objRte = objDom.createElement("rte")
        objGpx.appendChild objRte
    End If

    Set objRtept = objDom.createElement("rtept")

        'Create "Lat" attribute'
        Set objattLat = objDom.createAttribute("lat")
        objattLat.Text = (location_x)
        objRtept.setAttributeNode objattLat

        'Create "Lon" attribute'
        Set objattLon = objDom.createAttribute("lon")
        objattLon.Text = (location_y)
        objRtept.setAttributeNode objattLon

        'Create "date_and_time" element'
        Set objDateTime = objDom.createElement("time")
        objDateTime.Text = (date_and_time)

    'Append "rtept" element as a child container element "rte".'
    objRte.appendChild objRtept
    'Append the "time" element as a child of the "rtept" element'
    objRtept.appendChild objDateTime

    If blnFileExists = False Then
        'Create the xml processing instruction - and append to XML file
        Set objPI = objDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
        objDom.insertBefore objPI, objDom.childNodes(0)
    End If

    'Save the XML document.
    objDom.save strXMLFilePath & "\" & strFileName

    Set objDom = Nothing
    Set objGpx = Nothing
    Set objWpt = Nothing
    Set objRte = Nothing
    Set objRtept = Nothing
    Set objDateTime = Nothing
    Set objattLat = Nothing
    Set objattLon = Nothing
    Set objPI = Nothing
    Set blnFileExists = Nothing

End Function
%>
```

**example.xml Output (*prettified manually*):**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx>
  <wpt lat="56" lon="43">
    <time>26.09.2016 16:08:49</time>
  </wpt>
  <rte>
    <rtept lat="56" lon="43">
      <time>26.09.2016 16:08:49</time>
    </rtept>
    <rtept lat="56" lon="43">
      <time>26.09.2016 16:08:49</time>
    </rtept>
  </rte>
  <wpt lat="56" lon="43">
    <time>26.09.2016 16:08:49</time>
  </wpt>
</gpx>
```

Comment: Could you expand on your answer? I have altered the script as per your explanation but receive an error.

Comment: @Jonathan What was the error? I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's perfect!

Comment: @Jonathan thanks. I've added some additional information about `selectSingleNode` you might want to read.